# Oracle Advanced Secuity encryption with Spring JDBC xml configuration

Tags: spring, oracle, encryption, jdbc, configuration

Is there a way to bring the encryption features of Oracle advanced
Security into Spring JDBC dataSource configuation?

The DBA told me to pass the following arguments into the connection on client side.

```
sqlnet.encryption_client = requested
sqlnet.encryption_types_client = (RC4_128)
sqlnet.crypto_checksum_client = requested
sqlnet.crypto_checksum_types_client = (MD5)
```

According to the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/clntsec.htm#i1022564), encryption can be set for thin driver, by adding the arguments to the OracleConnection via good old `java.util.Properties`.

However, I can not find a way doing this with my Spring  `dataSource.xml` configuration.

The dataSource bean works fine:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="URL" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${datasource.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

But unfortunately the required properties aren't understood and bring the following Exception

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'encryption_client' of bean class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource]`

---

```
<property name="encryption_client" value="${datasource.encryption_client}"/>
    <property name="encryption_types_client" value="${datasource.encryption_types_client}"/>
    <property name="crypto_checksum_client" value="${datasource.crypto_checksum_client}"/>
    <property name="crypto_checksum_types_client" value="${datasource.crypto_checksum_types_client}"/>
```

1. In the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html#orcl.datasource.options) I see that there are only a handful attributes mentioned.
2. Looking again at the example in the *Oracle Documentation*, the properties are set like this
   `OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();ods.setProperties(prop)` 
   ... but the **API**  hasn't a `setProperties()` method.
   (https:// docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html)

I'm quite confused :(

Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

> **TL;TR** 
>  Is there any solution for handing over these Oracle encryption properties to Spring?

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle properties are not given in the Spring DataSource API so you have to set the additional properties after the bean is inited. You can do this with a class that implements 'beanpostprocessor'. Also, since this is Spring you need to get a handle to the current dataSource to set the additional properties without blowing up the bean init. You cannot use Autowire in the class cause then the PostProcessor will skip that bean. So, you have to cast the bean. Then you can use setConnectionProperties to init the parameters required by Oracle rather than setting the properties in the Spring bean which will not work and gives the error described above.

Also you should fix the title of this topic Secuity-->Security. Sorry if the formatting is off as I am new to posting answers.

```
@Component
public class OracleConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {


final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleConfigurer.class);
    if (bean instanceof DriverManagerDataSource) {
          Properties properties = ((DriverManagerDataSource) bean).getConnectionProperties();
          if (null == properties) properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "(AES256)");
                properties.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client", "REQUIRED");
                properties.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REQUIRED");
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = ((DriverManagerDataSource) bean);
                dataSource.setConnectionProperties(properties);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws
        BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Feature is introduced as part of Oracle Data Encryption and security standard

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/network.1111/e10746/asojbdc.htm#i1006157

With Respect to your Example Code , You were trying to inject values to String ,but as per the DriverManager [ Ex ojdbc jar], datasource is OracleDataSource
Decompiled Code Reference of ojdbc.jar will look like

```
public class OracleDataSource
 protected Properties connectionProperties = null;
```

The Class expects Properties as Bean instead of String

If you can set like shown Below or Inject Properties into Spring Xml, it would work without any custom code

```
  <bean id="dataSource"
    class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="URL" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${datasource.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
<property name="connectionProperties">
        <props>
        
     <prop key="oracle.net.encryption_client">REQUIRED</prop>
    <prop key="oracle.net.encryption_types_client">( AES256 )</prop>
    <prop key="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client">REQUIRED</prop>
    <prop key="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client">( SHA1 )</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

This should inject the properties collect to the OracleDataSource making to compliant to CLient side security

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to OracleConnection which have the correct name for security related connection properties. 
For Example:

```
Properties connProps = new Properties();

// For Data Integrity Check    connProps.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_TYPES, "( MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384 or SHA512 )");    connProps.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_LEVEL, "REQUIRED");

// For Data Encryption    connProps.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL, REQUIRED");    connProps.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES,"(DES40C)");

// OracleDataSource – Oracle JDBC Connection
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setConnectionProperties(connProps);
```

Also, refer to Security section of [Connection Management Strategies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc-ucp-conn-mgmt-strategies-3045654.pdf) whitepaper and also [Security](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) Whitepaper.

Comment: Thank you @Nirmala. Your example pushed me in the right direction. The XML bean seems to be too restrictive in this regard.