# How can I set Oracle encryption properties in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am trying to set some of these Oracle native encryption properties using Spring.

```
CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL
CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES
CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_LEVEL
CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_TYPES
```

I am unable to find how to do this with Spring.

[This link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asojbdc.htm#i1006209) explains how to achieve this using JDBC, but not using Spring. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464225/oracle-advanced-secuity-encryption-with-spring-jdbc-xml-configuration) is almost the same question, but I don't see a solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all these security properties in a property object use it by spring later:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES, 
"("+AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES256+",");
 prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_TYPES,
"("+AnoServices.CHECKSUM_SHA1+")");
```

And those instructions:

```
OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL,AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED);
OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_LEVEL,AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED);
```

Inject also your password and login and invoke a connection with these properties.